# Print a dictionary in an Excel file c#

Tags: c#, excel, dictionary

I have a dictionary named "DictionnaireFinal" that contain word for key and definition for value and I want to export it in an Excel File so i tried this :

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = oXL.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)oXL.ActiveSheet;


        oXL.Visible = true;

        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Mot";
        ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Definition";

        for(int i=2; i<= DictionnaireFinal.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach(var b in DictionnaireFinal)
            {
                ws.Cells[i, 1] = b.Key;
            }
        }
        for (int j=2; j<= DictionnaireFinal.Count; j++)
        {
            foreach (var b in DictionnaireFinal)
            {
                ws.Cells[j, 2] = b.Value;
            }
        }
```

When I execute the code, the excel file return just the "mot" and "definition" but nothing from the dictionary. 
Can someone help me please.
Thank You

Comment: What is `DictionnaireFinal`? What is in it? How many items?

Comment: What is the use for the `for` *and* `foreach`?

Comment: Using he Excel Interop is inefficient and isn't very user friendly.  Better to create a csv file which can easily be opened in Excel.

Comment: dictionnaireFinal is a dictionnary that stores all the word (key --> string) and definition(value --> string) , the number of items depends of how many words will find my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple unnecessary loop avoiding that following lines of code should work fine.

```
ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Mot";
ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Definition";

int row = 2;
foreach(DictionaryEntry b in DictionnaireFinal)
{
   ws.Cells[row , 1] = b.Key;
   ws.Cells[row , 2] = b.Value;
   row++;
}
```

Comment: thank you it works

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Startup
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application oXL = new Application();
        Workbook wb = oXL.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)oXL.ActiveSheet;

        Dictionary<int, string> DictionnaireFinal = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        DictionnaireFinal.Add(1, "vit");
        DictionnaireFinal.Add(2, "vito");
        DictionnaireFinal.Add(3, "vitya");

        oXL.Visible = true;

        ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Mot";
        ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Definition";

        int i = 1;

        foreach (var b in DictionnaireFinal)
        {
            i++;
            ws.Cells[i, 1] = b.Key;
            ws.Cells[i, 2] = b.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what you get:

[image]